# Where is this file in Windows? /home/f515c326-589b-4129-8fbc-af1053ae8b58/deneme.txt

Tags: python, file, anaconda, find

```
dosya = open(“deneme.txt”, “w”)
print(“Ben Python, Monty Python!”, file=dosya)
dosya.close()
```

After

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

the result

```
/home/f515c326-589b-4129-8fbc-af1053ae8b58/deneme.txt
```

this is looking like kind a linux etc. where is the this file I look everywhere with file explorer after I use the cmd but I don't find :(

my expecting

```
C:\Users\Mert\Desktop
```

Comment: Please do not use excessive caps lock and exclamation marks.

Comment: I don't know anything about your python installation, but it seems like it's running in some sort of container with an unixish file structure. Either try changing the current working directory prior to writing the file to a 'known location' or use os.path.join to create a path to write to.